# An ingenious exact smallest grammar algorithm for strings over a single letter, $s \in \{a\}^*$. First enumerate the start rules up to commutation

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, optimization, formal-grammars, combinatorics

Take $s = a^{10}$ for our example string.   Compute the set of all potential grammar reducing variable-rules:

$$
A \to aa \\
B \to aaa \\
C \to aaaa \\
D \to aaaaa 
$$

There is always exactly $\left\lfloor \dfrac{|s|}{2}\right\rfloor - 1$ of these over a singleton alphabet, or in other words $O(|s|)$.

Now enumerate all possible start *reduced* rules up to commutation of the variables.  Everything commutes over a singleton alphabet!  Note that because these rules are reduced, we will not see $AABB \simeq ABAB$ because clearly you can reduce that, where $\simeq$ is equivalence by commuting symbols (they expand to the same string i.e.).  *Note that to compute just one smallest grammar, it is sufficient to only search for reduced smallest grammars*.

$$
S \to ABCa \\
S \to AAAC \\
\vdots
$$

So the rule here is you can have $1$ to $3$ copies of one variable and single copies of the other variables, and everything must expand to $S \to s = a^{10}$.  I can see and easily enough prove this.

So all of these look like (dropping the "$S \to$" notationally):

$$
ABCa \\
ABD \\
AADa \\
AAAC \\
BBC \\
BBBa \\
ACC \\
CDa \\
DD
$$

Those are all that I could figure out off the top of my head, but of course an algorithm for enumerating them is not the critical part of this discussion.  Those are all possible RHS's $\gamma$ of start rules $S \to \gamma$ in any reduced grammar for $s$, up to commutation of the symbols (i.e. the total number of possibilities is too much to count, but we can do it up to commutation).  Remember, the reduced smallest grammars are a non-empty subset of the reduced grammars.  So the reduced grammars can make up our sufficient search space.

I have two questions:

1. What is the approximate order or Big-O notation for the number of possible irreducible start rules in the $|\Sigma|$ symbols where in the example $\Sigma = \{A, B, C, D, a\}$, i.e. the size of the above enumeration?
2. How should the algorithm then recurse?  It's as if you need to form all $k$-tuples of strings:

$$
(ABCa, aa, Aa, AA) \\
(ABCa, aa, Aa, C)\\
\vdots
$$

for where $k$ depends on each case's number of involved variables, so it's like doing the first enumeration but $(k-1)$-fold simultaneously, minding the already set start rule RHS.

A last question:

> Does this algorithm have a polynomial-time feeling about it?

---

The initial list of possibly needed-to-be-considered start rules can actually be shortened to:

$$BBC, DD, ACC, BBBa$$

If we apply the fact that for example $B = Aa, C = Ba = AA, D = AB$, etc.  Because if you look at $ABCa \simeq AaBC$; this can clearly be reduced by the presence of $B$ in the grammar to: $BBC$, and similarly for the other above-listed start rule possibilities.

Comment: Possibly related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain

Comment: @D.W. that is related, but also my approach is something new.

Comment: @D.W.  This algorithm will compute an optimal smallest grammar for $s = a^n$ I think in polynomial time in $n$.    So if you apply it to exponention / addition chains, you'll get _the most optimal way_ to exponentiate.  But a better application for it is theoretical.  I.e. perhaps we can generalize it to handle a binary alphabet $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$.